# Impossible to download FLV files on Android?

Tags: android, flash, video, download, flv

I'm thinking if it would be possible to write an app for Android which would allow a user to download flash videos from a website without making the user to start playback of every video manually in a browser. The app should also ideally work for any website playing flash videos and not just some specific websites. The app should not require root.

After doing my homework and googling a lot I came to the conclusion that such an app is not possible but I just wanted more experienced people to confirm this (or maybe suggest workarounds if I am wrong).

How such an app could (theoretically, ideally) work:

1. the app starts a service which runs in a background thread and doesn't even require an opened activity.
2. the service loads the webpage (html file) where the video is
3. the app parses the page to find the .swf file which normally plays the video
4. the app somehow sends a fake click to the action script in the swf file as if the user pressed "Play"
5. after a short while the app checks the cache of the webview (yet, there is no activity shown to the user). If there are any .flv files in the cache, it copies them, say, to some folder on SD card

In this scheme multiple things would probably fail:

in 3: I'm not sure one can emulate a click on Play button for the swf file, especially if we don't know what exact website we are on (we want the app to work on any website) and websites use their own, custom-written swf flash players. Also I'm not sure the .swf file would even be in a state where it could receive input if we don't even have a running activity

in 4: web cache is stored under /data/data/app_package_name/cache/webViewCacheChromium and this folder is not accessible even for the app itself (?) unless the phone is rooted.

I guess that's it, so it shouldn't be possible to make such an app.

Btw, does the FVD extension for Google Chrome get FLV files by scanning the Chrome browser cache?

Thanks!

EDIT: I know that Youtube now uses html5, I'm not looking to download Youtube videos.

EDIT: I've seen apps that work with specific websites (e.g. with Youtube) but making such an app is not viable since websites change ways they deliver flv files as basic defense. My question is about starting fake playback and getting the video files which are already in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible:

**1**: Where does the "website" come from? Are you going to catch when the user opens his browser and types in a website? If so, this is not possible.

I suppose you will get the "website" from somewhere.

---

**2** You do not need to emulate the play button: you only need the .flv file. It is pretty easy to scrape the website for the .swf file using any available tool. [You can try jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

---

**3** Sometimes, the swf gets this file in the usual param approach. For example `<embed bla bla link="http://website/file">` You just need to scrape and get this file.

---

**4** Now if the link to the file is not available, you will have to decompile the swf file. This is the challenging part. [Check some of the available tools here](http://bruce-lab.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/freeswfdecompilers.html). With hard work, you might be able to get a result. I say so because there are already lots of tools out there that do what you want. [Keepvid is in java](http://www.keepvid.com/) for example.

Comment: Thanks! The points 1-3 seem to be easy, the hard part comes with decompiling swf. Since each swf can work in a different way, I still can't write a universal solution for ALL websites. Instead, I'd have to decompile an swf from each website (e.g. youtube, 4shared, 5min..) manually first, see how it works and implement a website-specific way to get the flv. This is a solution but a costly one. Such an app would be very hard to support. I already see the 1-star reviews with "doesn't work" comments piling up as soon as one of my target websites changes their swf files.

Comment: @iseeall. I must say I am not expert in these kind of apps. But since I use apps that fetch download links from many websites, I always wondered how do they do it. That's what I got. I am sure it is very hard. Before fetching the link, I do not think it is straight forward to get a swf decompilation library to work on Android. If it does, you will probably have to come up with some algorithm (maybe some AI) that can fetch links from these codes. I can only assume how tedious this would be. I hope someone comes with an easier approach if any.

Comment: :) Thanks anyway, i gave the bounty amount for your reply. Yes, it seems to be the purpose of having Flash videos on a website instead of usual video files - to make downloading very difficult. I'll probably concentrate on just a few flash websites and see how they fetch their FLV's

Comment: It happens that I was just checking vimeo! and I must say it is hard. I managed to decompile. I am trying to get the stream url and it is close to impossible here

Comment: Also checked some websites and it just confirms that making "downloader" apps for them is not economically viable (I mean, considering the potential earnings one can get and the constant hassle one has to go into to keep up with their changing defenses).